# Imports from testing folder in Python

Tags: python, import

I am writing a simple Pong game and am having some trouble with imports in my testing. My project structure is as follows:

```
app/  
    __init__.py  
    src/  
        __init__.py  
        Side.py  
        Ball.py  
    test/  
        __init__.py  
        SideTests.py
```

in Side.py, I have:

```
from math import sqrt, pow

class Side:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def collision(self, ball):
        # returns True if there is a collision
        # returns False otherwise
```

(the details of the algorithm don't matter). In Ball.py, I have:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, position, direction, speed, radius):
        self.position = position
        self.direction = direction
        self.speed = speed
        self.radius = radius
```

in SideTests.py, I have:

```
import unittest
from src.Side import Side
from src.Ball import Ball

class SideTests(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
       self.side = Side([0, 0], [0, 2])
      self.ball_col = Ball([1, 1], [0, 0], 0, 1)

  def test_collision(self):
     self.assertTrue(self.side.collision(self.ball_col))
```

When I run:

```
python test/SideTests.py
```

from app/, I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/SideTests.py", line 15, in test_collision
    self.assertTrue(self.side.collision(self.ball_col))
AttributeError: Side instance has no attribute 'collision'
```

I know this is probably a very simple import error, but none of the examples I've looked at have helped solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix the indentation and imports at SideTests.py

```
import unittest
from app.Side import Side
from app.Ball import Ball

class SideTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.side = Side([0, 0], [0, 2])
        self.ball_col = Ball([1, 1], [0, 0], 0, 1)
```

You also do not need `test/__init__.py`.

Now to run this you either need to install a package called `app` in a virtualenv or globally, or use a tool that will collect relative imports for you before running tests, like nosetests which you can pip install.

```
~/app $ nosetests .
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: I ended up creating a package of my project, following the directions at http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/minimal.html, which solved my problem.